# Почему при использовании datetime() не корректно рассчитывается время?

Tags: python, datetime

Подскажите почему результат выполнения такого кода: 10

```
import datetime


def get_days_passed(date_string):
        input_date = datetime.datetime(
            int(date_string[:4]),
            int(date_string[5:7]), 
            int(date_string[8:10])
        )
        return (datetime.datetime.today()-input_date).days


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(get_days_passed('2018-01-12')) # output: 10
```

А результат такого 0:

```
def get_days_passed(date_string):
    input_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return (datetime.datetime.today()-input_date).days


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_days_passed('2018-01-12')) # output: 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем так сложно? `datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-12', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Ну да, я как раз и указал ниже такой вариант, хочу понять почему логика не работает в сложном вариенте. Потратил полтора часа своей жизни. Если не разберусь, это сильно задемотивирует)

Comment: хммм, у меня обе ваши функции возвращают `2`

Comment: @MaxU А, забыл добавить у меня системное время сбито, на моих часах сегодня 2018-01-12. Т.е. первая у вас тоже работает?

Comment: замечательно работает! Хотя пере-изобретать колесо - не есть правильно ;)

Comment: @MaxU А в чем тогда может быть проблема? приложил скриншот.

Comment: посмотрите на индексы внимательно

Comment: @Serg4356, у вас код на скриншоте другой ;) `date_string[9:10]` - вернет `4` - вот и весь секрет...

Comment: Не стою на месте) суть та же, и результат 10. Индексы тоже по всякому менял. В аутпуте. по-строчно - как считывается разрез строки, как он преобразуется в числа, как из него получается datetime, результат функции и текущий datetime

Comment: Точно, спасибо всем) Видимо когда менял индексы менял только те что в print были

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно посчитать разницу между одним и другим днем, в datetime есть для этого timedelta, попробуйте ее:

```
from datetime import timedelta
d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
(d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
```

Output:
   (-1, 86399, 999999)

Код стащен [отсюда](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)